# there is a way to have multiple sorting in react-admin?

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

I have a nodejs backend using [epilogue](https://github.com/dchester/epilogue), which supports multiple sort values like: `?sort=first_name,-rating` .

I am using a pretty standard [dataProvider](https://github.com/dunghuynh/aor-epilogue-client/blob/master/src/index.js) and I wondering how enable this feature in a react-admin List when I clicked over a label field.

How can I do that? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for future visitors, the request to have this feature was closed in https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/issues/2602

> We won't support it in the core. I suggest you write your own Datagrid to support that.